# Rebuild Search indexes error: "System.ArgumentException"

Tags: content-search, lucene

My "Rebuild search indexes" aborts and produces this error:

"System.ArgumentException: it doesn't make sense to have a field that is neither indexed nor stored".

but which field, which Item ID? without the specifics..

Is there a more comprehensive diagnostic? I'm in the /logs directory but nothing significant.

I relaunch, and now I've got a different exception:

> "RebuildSearchIndex|System.IO.IOException: Cannot overwrite:
>   C:\Sitecore\AJN\Data\indexes__system_1a0w.fdt    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.InitOutput(String name) "

Not sure what the next step is? Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `CrawlingLog` and `SearchLog` to see if there is any more detailed information (assuming you are checking the default log right now). If there isn't, you can turn on **VerboseLogging** which will give you a ton more information to follow up on: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/the_search_and_indexing_log_files. (Different Sitecore versions may enable that slightly differently). You should be able to find the field with the issue in the logs after that.

You can also check your `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page to see the list of defined fields in each index. In all likely-hood, one of those things is not like the others and it may help you pinpoint which config in the directory is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you  Rondel for your answer, I set VerboseLogging=true and have confirmation of the setting in the log. However at the moment it's still reluctant to spit information, closer to deaf and dumb than verbose ;)

Comment: For /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx, I've got an XML page currently if I paste this from the Control panel. But maybe there's some assumed know-how, or maybe I should see a "Showconfig" button or tab in the control panel?